# how to reduce javascript code using $this or passing vars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the entire test code.

In the end I will have numerous sliders and input fields with different IDs (no pattern) so I want to use $this or pass vars rather than having a bunch of repeated code.

There will be 3 max-values of the sliders: 5, 10, 15

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider1" ).slider({
            value:0, min: 0, max: 5, step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount1" ).val( $( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) );

        $( "#slider2" ).slider({
            value:0, min: 0, max: 10, step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount2" ).val( $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" ) );

        $( "#slider3" ).slider({
            value:0, min: 0, max: 15, step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount3" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount3" ).val( $( "#slider3" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .steps {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        position: relative; 
        height: 30px;
    }
    .tick { 
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1.2em;
        margin-left: -.6em;
        text-align:center;
        left: 0;
    }
    .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
        width: 2em;
        height: 3em;
        top: -1.4em;
        margin-left: -1em;
    }
    .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
        border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
        background: #333;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="font-size: small;">

    <div style="display:block;margin:100px auto;padding:0 8%">
        <input type="text" id="amount1" style="border:0 none">

        <div id="slider1"></div>

        <div class="steps">
            <?php
            for ($i=0, $t=5; $i<=$t; $i++) {
                echo '<span class="tick" style="left:'.(100/$t*$i).'%;';
                if ($i==ceil($t/2)) echo 'font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;';
                echo '">|<br>'.$i.'</span>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:block;margin:100px auto;padding:0 8%">
        <input type="text" id="amount2" style="border:0 none">

        <div id="slider2"></div>

        <div class="steps">
            <?php
            for ($i=0, $t=10; $i<=$t; $i++) {
                echo '<span class="tick" style="left:'.(100/$t*$i).'%;';
                if ($i==ceil($t/2)) echo 'font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;';
                echo '">|<br>'.$i.'</span>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:block;margin:100px auto;padding:0 8%">
        <input type="text" id="amount3" style="border:0 none">

        <div id="slider3"></div>

        <div class="steps">
            <?php
            for ($i=0, $t=15; $i<=$t ; $i++) {
                echo '<span class="tick" style="left:'.(100/$t*$i).'%;';
                if ($i==ceil($t/2)) echo 'font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;';
                echo '">|<br>'.$i.'</span>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your sliders `data` attributes to hold slider values, min and max values, etc., and a distinct `class` and then init slider on them. An example would be:

```
<div style="display:block;margin:100px auto;padding:0 8%">
    <input type="text" id="amount3" style="border:0 none" class="slider_value">

    <div id="slider3" class="slider_container" data-value="0" data-min="0" data-max="15" data-steps="1"></div>

    <div class="steps">
        <?php
        for ($i=0, $t=15; $i<=$t ; $i++) {
            echo '<span class="tick" style="left:'.(100/$t*$i).'%;';
            if ($i==ceil($t/2)) echo 'font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;';
            echo '">|<br>'.$i.'</span>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
$(function(){
    var value, step, min, max, input;

    $('.slider_container').each(function(){
        input = $(this).prev('.slider_value');
        value = $(this).data('value');
        step  = $(this).data('steps');
        min   = $(this).data('min');
        max   = $(this).data('max');

        $(this).slider({
            value: value, 
            min: min, 
            max: max, 
            step: step,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).prev('.slider_value').val(ui.value);
            }
        });

        input.val($(this).slider("value"));
    });
});
```

Comment: That's close! but it only updates the last input field when the last slider moves. I deleted slider3 and same result when slider2 became last. only the last slider input gets updated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest code? I've edited my post a bunch of times, and the last edit had to do exactly with `slide` function.

Comment: SWEET! It looks like I must have copied your answer while you were working on a change. this works great.

Comment: Previously I could use onupdate an then set the slider with `document.getElementById("slider3").value = data['xyz'];`. How do I set the slider value using your code above? (I'm learning here). Or should this be posted as a new question?

Comment: You can still use `onupdate` event, only now you'd refer to your input as `$(this).prev('.slider_value').val(data['xyz'])`. This would get preceding element that has `class="slider_value"`. If you need to change the value of a certain slider programmatically, you can still use the `id` to get the slider you need, like `$("#slider3").slider('value', 7);` - this will set the value of slider `slider3` to 7.

Comment: thank you - trial and error and I'm learning. I figured it out finally. I guess when you work it a while you learn it better... Got it now!

Answer (score 0):

I think a loop would reduce duplicate code:

```
var numElements = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    var $slider = $('#slider'+i);
    var $amount = $('#amount'+i);
    $slider.slider({
       value:0, min: 0, max: 5, step: 1,
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $amount.val( ui.value );
       }
    });
    $amount.val( $slider.slider( "value" ) );
}
```

Comment: as stated: #slider and #amount will be a bunch of other IDs. Not just 1 through whatever.

Comment: "a bunch of other ids" does not really indicate that the ids do not follow a pattern - the answer I posted simplifies your example code and that is really all we have to work with. If you want to post more specific details I could revise my answer

Comment: edited original to indicated no pattern for final IDs